# Windres not compiling .rc file no matter what I do

Tags: c, winapi, mingw, windres

So I am making a desktop application using C and the Win32 API. I am also using CMake/Make in conjunction with MinGW. Everything went smoothly until I wanted to add an .rc file to the executable. From my understanding you write an .rc file which is then compiled to a .res file, then presumably you are supposed to embed it in the executable. Here's the problem however, when I attempt to compile the .rc file with the GNU utility `windres` it fails to compile. I always get the following error messages:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\windres.exe: can't open file `page:': Invalid argument
C:\Code\C\test\resources.rc:4: fatal error: when writing output to : No such file or directory
4 | IDI_TEST_ICON    ICON    "test.ico"
  |
compilation terminated.
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
```

This occurs with every .rc file I've tried, for completeness however, here is the current test file I am trying to compile:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
IDI_TEST_ICON   ICON    "test.ico"
```

And the `resource.h` file:

```cpp
#define IDI_TEST_ICON 101
```

So the final question is the following: Why doesn't windres compile the .rc file successfully? And what can I do about in the context of using MinGW?

**Edit 1**:
Worth noting is that I also converted the .rc file to ANSI format since windres is notorious for yielding peculiar errors when formatted in UTF-8. Yet, the same errors occur.

Comment: How are you invoking `windres` exactly?  The error message is complaining that `windres` can't *write* to the file named `page:`, which makes sense as that is not a valid filename.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am invoking it through the use of `windres -i resource.rc -o resource.res`.

Comment: Don't put an answer into your question. If you want to provide an answer, you are [invited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging in old forum threads I managed to find a "solution" that works. However I still find it peculiar that this solves the problem. I followed Brecht Sanders advise and downloaded a standalone build from [winlibs.com](https://winlibs.com). Even this didn't solve the problem which led me to investigate possible RC_COMPILER_FLAGS which ultimately led me to the `--use-temp-file` flag.

This flag acts as an alternate approach to compile `.rc` files since it excludes the use of `popen` (or the equivalent of it in Windows). According to the documentation this flag should be used if the implemenation of `popen` is buggy on the host. What is interesting here is that the documentation states that this is known to happen on certain non-english versions of Windows. In my case I am using the Swedish language version of Windows which might explain why this is occuring.

Thus the final solution turns out to be:

```
windres -i resource.rc -o resource.o --use-temp-file
```

Which ultimately yields an object file which can then be included in the `add_executable` call in CMake.

Answer (score 1):

`windres` actually generates an object file (in COFF format)

So you should run the command like this:

```bash
windres resource.rc -o resource.o
```

When I check the format of the generated file like this:

```bash
file resource.o
```

I get the following result:

```
resource.o: Intel amd64 COFF object file, no line number info, not stripped, 1 section, symbol offset=0x3c4c, 1 symbols
```

So you just need to include the generated `.o` file in the link step to include the resource.

For example when you run the following command you will get an `.exe` that won't run, but it will show the icon in Explorer:

```bash
gcc -shared -o resource.exe resource.o
```

Comment: Idiomatic (in Windows-world) would be `windres resource.rc -o resource.res` I think, but otherwise +1 from me.

Comment: Alright, but the problem seems to be a faulty windres version or something because when I run the first command in your post I am greeted by the same "can't open file `page:': Invalid argument" error message. Could it perhaps be a faulty windres install? Is my .rc file properly formatted?

Comment: Try a recent version of MinGW-w64 like the standalone build for Windows from https://winlibs.com/